# nested loops, return list that contain only even integers

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

```
def only_evens(lst):
    """ (list of list of int) -> list of list of int

    Return a list of the lists in lst that contain only even integers. 

    >>> only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]])
    [[4, 0, 6], [2]]
    """

    even_lists = []

    for sublist in lst:

        even_lists = []

    for sublist in lst:

        for numb in sublist:
            if numb[i]%2 == 0:
                even_list.append(sublist)

    return even_lists
```

I got this error: NameError: global name 'i' is not defined
and what is wrong with the body of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numb` is not a list but the actual value, you can chose to drop the index if it isn't important:

```
if numb%2 == 0:
```

Or change the loop to give you an index if the index is important:

```
for i in range(len(sublist)-1):
    if sublist[i]%2 == 0:
```

But in this case I would use enumerate:

```
for i, numb in enumerate(sublist):
    if numb%2 == 0:
```

As you are looking to only add lists that contain all evens then you may want to investigate the `else` clause for the `for` loop:

```
for numb in sublist:
    if numb%2 != 0:
        break
else:
    even_list.append(sublist)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as the error says: `i` is not defined.

You try to use the variable `i` here:

```
if numb[i]%2 == 0:
# here--^
```

but you never defined it.  Define `i` to fix the problem